# How to use a pure function to write following sum?

Tags: homework, pure-function

How to use a pure function to write following sum?
I have tried to use `FoldList`, but it is still not working.

[image]

Comment: `p = Total[(Rest@FoldList[Plus, 0, Range[#]])^-1] &`

Comment: it is not correct when i use n=10

Comment: If you clear any old definitions (`Clear["Global\`*"]`), solution provided by @cvgmt works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Try `RSolve`

```
\[Rho] = RSolveValue[{rho[n] - rho[n - 1] == 1/Sum[i, {i, 1, n}], rho[1] == 1}, rho, n]
(*Function[{n}, (2 n)/(1 + n)]*)

\[Rho][10]
(*20/11*)
```

Answer (score 5):

One does not need to invent something complicated, just write what you see

```
f[n_] := Sum[1/Sum[k, {k, m}], {m, n}]
f[10]
(*20/11*)
```

and in pure form

```
g = Sum[1/Sum[k, {k, m}], {m, #}] &
g@10
g@t
(*20/11*)
(*2 - 2/(1 + t)*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p = Function[n, Sum[2/k/(k + 1), {k, 1, n}]];
p[10] (* 20/11 *)
```

If you are really committed to using `Fold`, you could try:

```
p = Function[n, Last@Fold[
  With[{dn = #1[[1]] + #2}, {dn, #1[[2]] + 1/dn}] &,
  {0, 0}, GeneralUtilities`RangeIterator[n]]]
```